# MapBox web app map widget, Multiple 'paint' arguments. Adding Opacity and Radius fails

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, mapbox

I would like to combine the following two arguments in a mapbox webapp widget.

The first argument is the color of latitude and longitude points:
[image]

I also want to have the opacity argument added, so the map dots do not have a center, like this:
[image]

But when I try to add both arguments, the opacity argument is ignored.

```
var coorAddresses = [ [ -75.7040473, 45.418067,"Medium" ], [-75.7040473, 45.418067, "Medium"], [-79.32930440000001, 43.7730495, "Unknown"]]


$.getJSON(coodAddresses, function(data) {
              for(var itemIndex in data) {
                // push new feature to the collection
                featureCollection.push({
                                    "type": "Feature",
                                    "geometry": {
                                                "type": "Point",
                                                "coordinates": [data[itemIndex][0], data[itemIndex][1]]
                                                },
                                    "properties": {
                                                  "size_by": data[itemIndex][2],
                                                  "color_by": data[itemIndex][2]

                                                },
                                        });
                                       }
                                    });

map.on('load', function () {
            map.addLayer({
              "id": "points",
              "type": "circle",
              "source": {
              "type": "geojson",
                "data": {
                  "type": "FeatureCollection",
                  "features": featureCollection
                }
              },
              "paint": {
                "circle-color": [
                      'match',
                      ['get', 'size_by'],
                      'Easy',
                      '#e4f400',
                      'Medium',
                      '#f48a00',
                      'Unknown',
                      '#6af400',
                      /* other */ '#00e4f4'
                      ],
                "circle-radius": [
                      'match',
                      ['get', 'size_by'],
                      'Easy',
                      4,
                      'Medium',
                      7,
                      'Unknown',
                      2,
                      /* other */ 1000
                    ],

                  // "circle-opacity": 0, // color does not show if i uncomment these lines
                  // "circle-stroke-width": 1,  // do not get desired 'hollow' circle unless these lines run
            }});
```